# Change locations of titles, also add a transition

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to place both titles on opposite sides of the image. (Image at the bottom) "Seil" on the left and "Solseil" on the right. Here is the code I am using now to place them at the bottom. I use wordpress:

```css
.elementor-tabs-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 4; 
}
```

I also want to make a simple transition when I change between the pictures

Seil:

[image]

Solseil:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

With a display flex and justify content space between, you can make them go to the opposite side of the image (note that you also have to set the width to 100%.
For the transition, it depends on how your dom is. You can always try to add a transition : .5s; to see how it goes

Comment: I have no idea :/